# JOIN Tables with all specified fields matching

Tags: sql

I have two tables. I'm selecting all the values in the first table and trying to get the associated rows in the second table which match BOTH of the specified fields.

So in this example, I want only the rows in the CarsTable and the associated columns in the TrucksTable in which BOTH the Tires and Windows values match (if just one value matches, I don't want it). I'm not even certain a join is the correct operation. Any ideas?

```
SELECT * FROM CarsTable, TrucksTable
  LEFT JOIN TrucksTable t1
  ON 
  t1.Tires = Cars.Tires
  LEFT JOIN Trucks t2
  ON 
  t2.Windows = Cars.Windows
```

Comment: If all you want are the field that match then the inner join is all you need. Outer joins, be right or left, show the rows from either the right or left table that did not have a match in addition to the rows that did have a match. Clean up the joins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some research on joins...your from clause is all over the place.  Carstable,truckstable as you have here is a cross join..and I don't understand what the left joins you are doing are.  I think you only have two tables:

```
SELECT c.*, t.* FROM CarsTable c
inner join TrucksTable t
on t.tires = c.tires and t.windows = c.windows
```

inner join will function as a filter...if the record in carstable finds no matches in the truckstable by the keys listed, it won't appear.  If you want all cartable rows even those that find no match, use left join (in this case, t.* will be null)